# TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined Discord Bot js

Tags: discord.js

My problem is the following: when compiling, I get the error that the property 'execute' is not defined. What I'm trying to do is open a file that is in another folder and dock it in the if, I was guided by the command handling documentation, I don't know if the error is in the other file which is called 'ping.js'. I recently started, so I don't fully understand it.
The main code is as follows:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { token, default_prefix } = require('./conf.json');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const fs = require('fs');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}


client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('message', async message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(default_prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(default_prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === 'ping') {
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
    }
});

client.login(token);
```

While the 'ping.js' code is:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    description: "Get the latency of the bot.",
    usage: {},
    examples: {},
    aliases: [ "pong", "latency", "uptime" ],
    permissionRequired: 0,
    checkArgs: (args) => !args.length
  }

module.exports.run = async function (client, message, args, config, gdb, prefix, permissionLevel, db) {
    let botMsg = await message.channel.send("Pinging")
                    botMsg.edit({ 
                    embed: {
                    name: "ping",
                    title: " Ping",
                    color: 0x2ed32e,
                    description: [
                        "**Server**: `" + (message.createdAt - message.createdAt) + "ms`",
                        "**API**: `" + Math.round(client.ws.ping) + "ms`",
                        "**Uptime**: `" + msToTime(client.uptime) + "`"
                    ].join("\n"),
                    footer: { text: "Requested by " + message.author.tag, icon_url: message.author.displayAvatarURL }
                }
            })
        }

        function msToTime(ms) {...
        }
```

It works, but if I add it directly to the main code, but I don't want that. If you have any ideas or know the solution, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's saying `execute is undefined` because you didn't define `execute` it in `ping.js`.

You can do either:

- In `ping.js` change `module.exports.run` to `module.exports.execute`
- OR in your main file, change `client.commands.get('ping').execute` to `client.commands.get('ping').run`

The reasoning for the is when calling `command.execute()` you are attempting to call a function named 'execute' in the command's module. Since you named it `run` instead of `execute`, it looks for the wrong function and doesn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you named it `run` and not `execute` on this line:

`module.exports.run = async function ()`

change it to execute and it should work fine, if you wanna keep the keyword `run`, instead of `client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args)`, use  `client.commands.get('ping').run(message, args)`

Also I should mention you have a lot of parameters:

```
execute function (client, message, args, config, gdb, prefix, permissionLevel, db) {
   //...
}
```

Any after args will be undefined as you only pass in  messsage and args, here:

`client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args)`