# discord.js TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am attempting to make a bot for my discord server, everything runs fine until I get to my second command (beep). I'll go into my command prompt type "node ." and it will all come online, so I go to my discord server and type ~ping and it runs perfectly. But when I run beep my command prompt says, "TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined". I've tried everything I can find on google ad would really appreciate some help!

**main.js**

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = '~';

const fs = require('fs');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
const commandFIles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFIles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
    client.user.setActivity("Attack On Titan"); 
});

client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command == 'ping'){
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command == 'beep'){
        client.commands.get('beep').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command == 'server'){
        client.commands.get('server').execute(message, args);
    }
});

client.login('Super-Secret-Bot-Token');
```

**ping.js**

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'ping',
    description: 'Ping!',
    execute(message) {
        message.channel.send('Pong.');
    },
};
```

**beep.js**

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'Beep',
    description: 'It Boops.',
    execute(message) {
        message.channel.send('Boop!');
    },
};
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62567517/typeerror-cannot-read-property-execute-of-undefined-discord-bot-js

Comment: You try executing a command called `beep`, however you have the command itself named `Beep`. Since you lowercase the message, you are trying to compare `beep` to `Beep` which ofcourse is not the same since JS is case sensitive. Just lowercase the name of the command module